# Make jQuery wait for one .each function to complete before next line is executed?

Tags: jquery, callback, each

I have this:

```
$("a.fadeout").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var loc = this.href;

    //Do this first...
    $($(".faded").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeOut();
    });

    //And only then do this.. 
    window.location = loc;

});
```

How do I force the fadeouts to complete before the location changes? If it was just one fadeOut() I would use it's callback, but as there are many, I can't work out how to do it.

Cheers!
Ben

Comment: The issue here isn't with the `.each()` function, as it will complete before the next line is executed.  It is with the `.delay()` function, which delays for longer than it takes to run through the `.each()` function and execute the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [works](http://jsfiddle.net/Udj7V/2/);

```
$("a.fadeout").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var loc = this.href;
    var amount = $($(".faded").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeOut(function () {
            if (i == amount -1) {
                window.location = loc;
            }
        });
    }).length;
});
```

It's the cleanest way I can think of. We store the total amount of elements and check in the callback for `fadeOut` whether it's the last callback that was bound. If it is, it executes the redirect.

Comment: Won't work. The callback function of `.each(function(i) { ... })` is executed before the `length` attribute can be saved and made accessible in the `amount` variable. Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Udj7V/

Comment: @silvinci: that's not the case. The problem was `i` is zero indexed, and I missed the `-1` on the check; see http://jsfiddle.net/Udj7V/2/

Comment: You're right. Funny - we came to the same solution... but you managed to do it with less variables ;)

Answer (score 1):

It can be:

```
$("a.fadeout").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var loc = this.href;
    var list = $($(".faded").get().reverse());
    var size = list.length;
    var count = 0;
    list.each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeOut(function () {
            if (++count == size) {
                window.location = loc;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, this worked for me also, but I used Matt's because it looks just a little neater. Purely aesthetics :)

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same problem, please have a look at this link, it will help you to design a new callback : http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-callback-functions-for-your.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the event-based, non-linear world of **async**!

`$(this).delay(i * 100)` creates a new `setTimeout()`. And this does not cause the whole script to pause, otherwise the whole browser would freeze for this amount of time. jQuery offers some ways to deal with this kind of problem but in the way you do it it is not possible. You would have to do a check every time a `fadeOut()` is made.

```
$("a.fadeout").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var loc    = this.href,
        $stack = $(".faded").get().reverse();

    //Do this first...
    $($stack).each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeOut().queue(function() {
            if($stack.lenght <= i+1) {
                window.location = loc;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Test it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Udj7V/3/).

Comment: Thanks. The solution didn't work for me (I did fix the comma > semicolon error), but thanks for explaining the issue, I'll look into the async nature of these sorts of scripts a bit more!